# Redirect programs directly to eclipse console

Tags: c, eclipse, accessibility, eclipse-cdt, jaws-screen-reader

I am using eclipse cdt oxygen with mingw64 7.2.0 on windows 10 to write programs in c. Whenever I write programs that only outputs like:

```
printf("x\n");
```

The output got printed into the console. However when I write programs that asks for inputs, like:

```
c = getchar();
```

rather than going to the console, eclipse instead opens a terminal. I believe that is where you will type the input. This doesn't usually bother me, however my eyes are destroyed, I am using a screen reader and this terminal is somewhat inaccessible. It is usable, but can be very hard to use sometimes (E.G. my screen reader JAWS does not speak what I'm typing).

Is there a way for eclipse cdt to put all inputs and outputs directly to the console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately in this case eclipse console is read only. Better once compile and build your code go to the folder where it created your `exe` file and run that `exe` in command prompt and test.

1. open command prompt window (type cmd)
2. cd C:\path_to_your_exe\
3. yourexe

This will also help you in case your program takes command line parameters.